# How to find Values based on Effective Date in a C# list using LinQ

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a C# list containing following values

```
*ItemID EffectiveDate   EffectiveDate   Rate** 
Item1   1/1/2017    oz  10
Item1   1/1/2017    lb  150
Item1   1/1/2018    oz  11
Item1   1/1/2018    lb  160
Item1   1/1/2019    oz  12
Item1   1/1/2019    lb  170
Item2   1/1/2017    oz  21
Item2   1/1/2017    lb  220
Item2   1/1/2018    oz  22
Item2   1/1/2018    lb  225
Item2   1/1/2019    oz  23
Item2   1/1/2019    lb  235
```

and Bill in following format

```
**Bill Detail**
ItemId, BillDate
Item1, 5/4/2017
Item1, 7/1/2019
Item2, 5/4/2018
Item3, 5/4/2019
```

I am looking for lambda expression using which I can find the Rates of Item based on effective Date.

For example, for ItemId = "Item1"  and BillDate = "5/4/2017", the output should be

```
Item1   1/1/2017    oz  10
Item1   1/1/2017    lb  150
```

Can you please help?

Comment: Did you tried to use `Where` extension method? Can you show what did you tried?

Comment: So, you are looking for a query to find the only **single** record **where** ItemID equals provided item ID and effective date lies between the provided date, right? :)

Comment: You have 2 lists then? On for each of the classes?

Comment: @fabio I realized i forgot to mention that i am expecting multiple records by types. When i apply the Where as Where(x => 
                                        (x.EffectiveDate < Bil.effectiveDate ) I can filter all the records which are less than effective date, but not able to filter it further to select max of effective date from filtered set.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev, after your comment, i realized I forgot to include the type attribute of the items. I am looking for more than one record for selected item based on their effective date and the Item Id.

Comment: @AustinTFrench, Yes, there are two lists, but i am passing Bill object as single object in a function to process so in the calling function, the bill is a class and not a list.

Comment: Some real code would be a lot more helpful (i.e. the class definitions and a line that instantiates a list), because it gives us something to use when writing a code sample for an answer.

Comment: It appears that the rows in your first sample have two columns named `EffectiveDate`, but only one of them contains a `Date` type?

Comment: var glist1 = list1.GroupBy(l=>l.ItemID).Select(l=>l.OrderBy(z=>z.EffectiveDate).ToList());  then join that to your list2, and use the projection (select) to only return the first EffectiveDate > that the entry in the bill list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to output the rates for each bill using the maximum `EffecitveDate` that's less than or equal to the bill date.

If so, here's one way. First, let's define the classes to make sure we're on the same page:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }
    public string UnitOfMeasure { get; set; }
    public int Rate { get; set; }

    public Item() { }

    public Item(string id, DateTime effectiveDate, string unitOfMeasure, int rate)
    {
        Id = id;
        EffectiveDate = effectiveDate;
        UnitOfMeasure = unitOfMeasure;
        Rate = rate;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Id} {EffectiveDate.ToShortDateString()} {UnitOfMeasure} {Rate}";
    }
}

public class Bill
{
    public string ItemId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{ItemId} {Date.ToShortDateString()}";
    }
}
```

Next, let's define our lists:

```
var items = new List<Item>
{
    new Item("Item1", new DateTime(2017, 1, 1), "oz", 10),
    new Item("Item1", new DateTime(2017, 1, 1), "lb", 150),
    new Item("Item1", new DateTime(2018, 1, 1), "oz", 11),
    new Item("Item1", new DateTime(2018, 1, 1), "lb", 160),
    new Item("Item1", new DateTime(2019, 1, 1), "oz", 12),
    new Item("Item1", new DateTime(2019, 1, 1), "lb", 170),
    new Item("Item2", new DateTime(2017, 1, 1), "oz", 21),
    new Item("Item2", new DateTime(2017, 1, 1), "lb", 220),
    new Item("Item2", new DateTime(2018, 1, 1), "oz", 22),
    new Item("Item2", new DateTime(2018, 1, 1), "lb", 225),
    new Item("Item2", new DateTime(2019, 1, 1), "oz", 23),
    new Item("Item2", new DateTime(2019, 1, 1), "lb", 235),
};

var bills = new List<Bill>
{
    new Bill {ItemId = "Item1", Date = new DateTime(2017, 5, 4)},
    new Bill {ItemId = "Item1", Date = new DateTime(2019, 7, 1)},
    new Bill {ItemId = "Item2", Date = new DateTime(2018, 5, 4)},
    new Bill {ItemId = "Item3", Date = new DateTime(2019, 5, 4)},
};
```

Now, assuming those are correct, here's a way you can print the output for each bill. For each bill, we first get the items that match the `ItemId`, and where the `EffectiveDate` is less than or equal to the bill `Date`. Then we group them by the `EffectiveDate` so items with the same date are in one group, then we can select the largest one if we `OrderBy` the `EffectiveDate` and then take the `LastOrDefault`:

```
foreach (var bill in bills)
{
    var rates = items
        .Where(item => item.Id == bill.ItemId && item.EffectiveDate <= bill.Date)
        .GroupBy(item => item.EffectiveDate)
        .OrderBy(grp => grp.Key)
        .LastOrDefault();

    Console.WriteLine($"For bill {bill}: ");
    Console.WriteLine(rates == null 
        ? " - [No rates]\r\n" 
        : $" - {string.Join("\r\n - ", rates)}\r\n");
}
```

**Output**

[image]